# Unable to create curved view in react-native

Tags: react-native

[image]

```
<View style={{
width: window.width,
height: window.width / 7, 
backgroundColor: colors.white}}>

<View style={{
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 80,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 80,
    height: window.width / 7,
    width: window.width,
    flex: 1,
}}>
    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        height: window.width / 7,
        width: window.width / 3,
        borderRadius: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    }}>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Consider adding text to further explain the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Check the below solution

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function Curve() {
  return (
    <View style={{ margin: 50 }}>
      <View style={styles.squreStyle} />
      <View style={styles.arcStyle} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  squreStyle: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 12,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  arcStyle: {
    width: "20%",
    height: 70,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: -25,
    left: "40%",
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    transform: [{ scaleX: 5 }, { scaleY: 1 }],
  },
});
```

Sample image of the working code
[image]

**Edit** - Modified according to the requirements of Scroll & Write content inside header.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";

export default function Curve() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{marginVertical: 50}}>
        <View style={styles.squreStyle}>
          <Text style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>Sample Header</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.arcStyle} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ height: 500, backgroundColor: "green" }} />
      <View style={{ height: 500, backgroundColor: "yellow" }} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  squreStyle: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 12,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  arcStyle: {
    width: "20%",
    height: 70,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: -25,
    left: "40%",
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    transform: [{ scaleX: 5 }, { scaleY: 1 }],
  },
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: How would you write content now inside this 'header'? Because they are separate `Views`?

Comment: Also, by using `position: absolute`, this won't be able to scroll anymore, if someone wants to use a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Scrolling won't be an issue only thing that you have to do is wrap the above code using ```ScrollView```. what you mean by the content inside ```header``` could you explain your requirement a bit more.

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to have a picture instead of black, how would I do it?

Comment: @BenB where do you want to place the image?

Comment: So the image will only be seen, instead of the black screen. Inside the entire header.

Comment: @BenB I haven't tried that. you can replace ````Text``` of ```header``` with an ```Image``` component but you also have to change the ```squreStyle``` as well.

Comment: @Sunil Mishra was this answer enough to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: img]

The thing is react native doesnt let us add border radius to sides unless of same height and width so that it can be a circle. What i did is exactly created a circle and pushed it upwards with `top` so that it seems like this. You can control the curvature by fixing the height and width and make it dynamic so that in every screen it looks the same.
Please check code below and also the expo snack:

[expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/5HqW330a7)

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.newD}></View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,

  },
  newD:{
    height:500,
    width:500,
    backgroundColor:'red',
    marginLeft:-70,
    borderRadius:500,
    top:-280
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: This is complete circle, if you see image it is not circle

Comment: yes thats why i said, you can attain the curvature by height and width, try once

Comment: i need arc rather than a circle

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-canvas for draw it

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';
const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
...
drawArc = (canvas) => {
  const height = 150;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.moveTo(0,height/2);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(width/2, height, width, height/2);
};
...


<Canvas
  ref={canvas => drawArc(canvas) />

...
```

Hope this helps to you.