# How to curve a line in react native

Tags: react-native

How can i achieve a curve line in react native.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvHqi.png)

I tried border radius but could not achieve this result.Thanks.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61454520/9432559

Comment: i cannot achieve that result using that method.Its better if i can curve a line.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve a curved line in react-native.

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
  <View style={styles.container} />
  <View style={styles.curvedLine} />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 12,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  curvedLine: {
    width: "20%",
    height: 100,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: -25,
    left: "40%",
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    transform: [{ scaleX: 5 }, { scaleY: 1 }],
  },
});
```