# Curved concave bottom react Native

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to create a curved div, curved at bottom but concave one.
I'm new to React Native and found a lot of examples for convex div.

[image]

Comment: Clip-path  ellipse, is an option, pseudo and shadow or background gradient are others. Have you tried any yet?

Comment: this might helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/61421129/9432559

Comment: @SDushan I want to build a concave curved div, with curve inwards. borderBottomLeftRadius doesn't allow to curve inwards.